# "Inappropriate file type or format"

Tags: c, operating-system, archive

I am trying to add a new file member with ar_hdr format and put it right after the last element in an archive.  My code compiles, but when I want to view the file name with the ar -t command, I got an error message that says: ar: hello.a: Inappropriate file type or format.  Can someone take a look at my code and give me some hints on how to fix it?  Thanks.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/utsname.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ar.h>

#define BLOCKSIZE 1

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    char *archive = argv[1];
    char *read_file = argv[2];

    int in_fd;
    int out_fd;

    char title[] = ARMAG;   //constant define in ar.h
    char buf[BLOCKSIZE];

    int num_read;
    int num_written;

    struct stat stat_file;
    struct ar_hdr my_ar;

    //open read_file (i.e., text file)
    if (stat(read_file, &stat_file) == -1){
        perror("Error in Stat");
        exit(-1);
    }

    //assign file info to struct dhr (my_ar)    
    sprintf(my_ar.ar_name, "%s", read_file);
    sprintf(my_ar.ar_date, "%ld", stat_file.st_mtimespec.tv_sec);
    sprintf(my_ar.ar_uid, "%i", stat_file.st_uid);
    sprintf(my_ar.ar_gid, "%i", stat_file.st_gid);
    sprintf(my_ar.ar_mode, "%o", stat_file.st_mode) ;
    sprintf(my_ar.ar_size, "%lld", stat_file.st_size) ;


    //0666 - open archive
    out_fd = open(archive, O_CREAT | O_WRONLY | O_APPEND, 0666);
    if (out_fd == -1) {
        perror("Canot open/create output file");
        exit(-1);
    }

    //write my_ar to archive
    num_written = write(out_fd, title, sizeof(title));
    num_written = write(out_fd, &my_ar, sizeof(my_ar));


    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Maybe to do with not setting the `ar_fmag` struct member (see http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19082-01/819-2242/ar.h-3head/index.html) - I have no experience with `ar` so this is a guess. Also it could be useful to analyse the output file with `od` to check that the bytes are as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

The `title` should only appear once in the file, at the very beginning. If you're appending a file to an archive, you just need to write the `ar_hdr` for the new file, followed by the contents of the file.

So you need to check whether the file already exists. If it doesn't, and you're creating a new archive, you need to write `title` first. If it does exist, skip that step. Since you're opening the file in append mode, you can tell whether it's a new file using `lseek()`:

```
off_t curpos = lseek(out_fd, SEEK_CUR, 0); // Get current position
if (curpos == 0) { // At beginning, it must be a new file
  num_written = write(out_fd, ARMAG, SARMAG);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I added what you suggested and added the contents of the file after the ar_hdr, but I'm still getting the same error. I'll post my new questions.

Answer (score 0):

user2203774, I'm going to re-iterate: You're working with a poorly-documented file format that is *not standardized*. The only way to know the correct file format is to (a) study the documentation links I gave in your other question, and (b) analyze a sampling of the archive files you have, to determine whether or not the format conforms to such documentation as you have. The likelihood is that the file format will be similar, but not identical. THEN, you need to figure out what the differences are. Once you do that, create your own file format document, and work off of that.

ALSO NOTE that the first and simplest debugging step is "*compare what my program generated with the equivalent as generated by `ar`. How are they different? Why?*" (The `od -c` command is helpful here, or a side-by-side hex viewer).

Several points:

- The magic header string (`"!<arch>\n"`) only goes at the start of the file, not at the beginning of every record.
- All the fields in the `ar_hdr` structure are filled with spaces, and *are not* null-terminated strings.
- Unless you're prepared to update the symbol table (including adding one if necessary) and rewrite the entire file, you must make sure your filenames do not exceed fifteen characters.
- Each filename must be immediately followed by a `/` character (which must not be followed by a null. Again, the rest of the field filled with spaces.)
- You're never initializing the `ar_fmag` field of the `ar_hdr` structure. This needs to be initialized to a specific value.
- After you write the header, you need to write the actual content of the file.
- Some references indicate that when the file content is written, you must write an even number of bytes. If the file size is an odd number, a single `\n` should be appended as padding (and the file size as recorded in the header is NOT incremented to include the padding byte).